# solr - define 1:n:n relationship

Tags: search, solr

I have created a flat table from my DB and defined a solr core on it.
It works excellent so far.

My problem is that my table has two hierarchies. So when flatted it is too big.
Lets consider the following example scenario

My Tables are

```
School
Students (1:n with school)
Teachers(1:n with school)
```

**EDIT:** Consider that all tables in my example have two columns: Name & Description which I would like to index and search and the searches are user generated freetext search over those columns.

Now, each school has many students and teachers but each student/teacher has another multivalue field. i.e. the following table

```
studentHobbies - 1:N with students
teacherCourses - 1:N with teachers
```

My main Entity is School and that what I want to get in the result. 
Flattening does not help me much and is very expensive.

**EDIT** Problems with query
When you query a flat table by school name, as I described, if the school has 300 student, 300 teachers, 300  with 300 teacherCourses, 300 studentHobbies,
    you get 8.1 Billion rows (300*300*300*300). Searching for the school name will retrieve 8.1 B rows.

Can you direct me to how I define 1:n:n relationships In data-config.xml

Thanks.

Comment: Can you povide information on additional fields that you are storing? i.e. students have studentHobbies, but what information are you storing wrt to school? What information will you be searching for?

Answer (score 0):

[Found it](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example)
a documentation of 1:n, 1:n:n and n:n relation